# VBS multiple looping .vbs on one PC

Tags: vbscript

Can VBS run two infinite loops?

I wrote an FTP downloader.

And I wrote a script that distributes the downloads to several folders.

Both are never-ending loops

Problems occur when I run them both: it seems only the .vbs started last, works error free.

When I start the distributor first, it fails later on when the ftp downloader is active and vice versa.

Could it be they "see" each others variables? I'm stuck and got no clue as to what is going on.

Could FileSystemObjects block each other? Claim folders or files so the other .vbs can't work with them?

Comment: Okay, voted down again. I can't post the scripts here as they are massive. Can VBS run two infinite loops?

Comment: Why use a loop and not schedule task?

Comment: what is the distributor and what is the downloader. They seem to be 2 different things

Comment: The downloader grabs files from the FTP and puts them in a buffer folder. Each file that seems okay, is then transferred to a ticket folder and deleted from the FTP. this is loop 1.

Comment: The distributor looks into the ticket folder and distributes the content over 4 node folders for rendering. This is loop 2.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot ftp.exe leads its own life outside of my VBS. The download was initated by the VBS and then the VBS jumped into handling the files. This can go wrong if the download hasn't finished.

Answer (score -1):

VBS cannot run two infinite loops, but you can use one to open another VBS script so you have two infinite loops running at once. a simpler way is to make a batch file that will run both files when started. It will also help if they are both in the folder.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).